# Excel top n list by criteria (including between dates)

Tags: excel, between

I am trying to figure out how to make a top n list of the most common textvalue in an excel spreadsheet based og 2 criterias (between dates and text).

Assuming i have a list as shown in image below. In columnE i want to be able to list the top n colors from columnB based on the criteria that it's a Bmw (columnA) sold within 2017 (ColumnC)

[image: excel spreadsheet]

Hope someone can help !

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: I manage to use an array formula to find the most frequent color, and also the 2nd, 3rd ans so on, but i have problem using criterias within the formulas.

Comment: Ever consider using pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use Pivot Tables, here's a way to achieve this:

Use Sold Date as filter, Car in Columns and Colour as Rows. Then have Count of Colour as Values.

On the row Labels filter, use Value filter and at the bottom you have Top 10... which you can set to top 3.

Answer (score 0):

Following might be helpful.

In `Cell G2` enter following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,MODE(IF(A$2:A$14=E2,IF(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2,MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0}))))),"")
```

In `Cell H2` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF((A$2:A$14=E2)*(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2)*
(B$2:B$14<>INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF(A$2:A$14=E2,IF(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2,MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0})))))),MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0})))),"")
```

In `Cell I2` enter the below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF(((A$2:A$14=E2)*(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2)*
(B$2:B$14<>INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF(A$2:A$14=E2,IF(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2,MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0}))))))*
(B$2:B$14<>INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF((A$2:A$14=E2)*(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2)*
(B$2:B$14<>INDEX(B$2:B$14,MODE(IF(A$2:A$14=E2,IF(YEAR(C$2:C$14)=F2,MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0})))))),MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0})))))),MATCH(B$2:B$14,B$2:B$14,{0,0})))),"")
```

All the above formulas are **array formula** so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.

***Note :*** In case there's a tie for any position, color appearing first in the range will be the result.

See image for reference.

[image]